# On Insert: column reference "score" is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql

I have the following command in postgresql:

```
INSERT INTO word_relations(word1_id, word2_id, score) VALUES($1, $2, $3)
ON CONFLICT (word1_id, word2_id) DO UPDATE SET score = score + $3`)
```

I get the following error:

```
column reference "score" is ambiguous
```

I thought it was odd as I am only using one table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

On the right side of the `=` in the `set` clause, there are two possibilities for `score`:  `EXCLUDED.score` and `word_relations.score`.  The former is a way of accessing the value being inserted; the latter a way of accessing the value stored in the row.

I would write this as:

```
ON CONFLICT (word1_id, word2_id) DO
    UPDATE SET score = word_relations.score + EXCLUDED.score
```

Comment: In which case will `word_relations.score` be different from `EXCLUDED.score`? Is there a reason for the split between them when its clearly stated that the conflict is on that column ??

Comment: word_relations.score is the old value, and EXCLUDED.score is the new one you're inserting now