# PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

Postgres documentation makes it seem like a WHERE clause is possible as an ON CONFLICT condition: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

I have not been able to get this working (if it's possible). Here is one of the many permutations I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO friends (id, dob, frn, status, "groupId", 
"createdAt", "updatedAt") 
VALUES ('1da04305-68ef-4dc1-be6c-
826ab83a6479', '1937-06-01T08:29:08-07:00', 100001, 'New', 'bc1567bc-
14ff-4ba2-b108-4cb2e0f0f768', NOW(), NOW()) 
ON CONFLICT 
    WHERE frn=100001 DO NOTHING
```

frn does not have any constraints, so the simpler syntax:

```
ON CONFLICT (frn) DO NOTHING
```

throws database errors. My hope is this is a simple syntax issue.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? uniqueness on `frn`? because in that case, you should have a unique constraint on `frn`.

Comment: frn is only unique within the context of a groupId. So the combination of a frn and a groupId are unique, but in isolation, a frn is not unique.

Comment: then, with the new `UPSERT` you can only do `ON CONFLICT ("groupId", frn)`. -- if you want to check only `frn`: there is no high-concurrency safe solution for that.

Comment: Yes, I think that would work if I added an exclusion constraint on the table. I'm still curious if a WHERE clause in the new UPSERT possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is subordinate to the `ON CONFLICT (constraint) DO UPDATE SET ...` clause.  It only looks at the single row that violated the specified constraint when trying to INSERT.

A syntactically valid example:

```
INSERT INTO friends (
    id, 
    dob, frn, status,
    "groupId", "createdAt", "updatedAt"
) VALUES (
    '1da04305-68ef-4dc1-be6c-826ab83a6479',
    '1937-06-01T08:29:08-07:00', 100001, 'New',
    'bc1567bc-14ff-4ba2-b108-4cb2e0f0f768', NOW(), NOW()
) 
ON CONFLICT ("groupId", frn) DO UPDATE SET
    status='Revised', 
    "updatedAt"=NOW()
WHERE friends.status<>'Deleted';
```

Or as an [operational example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1bfc26d5d1f0b3fca3f4cf10017cc852).

Comment: Note, you probably want to write it as `WHERE friends.status<>'Deleted'`, [as otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378646/on-insert-column-reference-score-is-ambiguous) you'll most likely get a `column reference "status" is ambiguous` error.

Comment: @Klesun, I am so glad you added a comment to this ancient thread, and just in time to solve my problem!

Comment: @Klesun what happens if where condition is false? 'DO NOTHING' vs 'duplicate key violation'

Comment: @valijon it will be 'DO NOTHING'.