# Postgres function update column ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I create a postgres function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_annotation_f(
    IN cmtid uuid)
    RETURNS bool AS $$
DECLARE
     pid uuid;
     cmt_cnt int4;
BEGIN
    SELECT get_comment_cnt_f(cmtid) INTO cmt_cnt;
    UPDATE detail_t SET ann_cmt_cnt=ann_cmt_cnt - cmt_cnt;
    RETURN TRUE;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I run this function I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "cmt_cnt" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...detail_t SET ann_cmt_cnt=ann_cmt_cnt-cmt_cnt WH...
```

I find this link [On Inset: column reference "score" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378646/on-inset-column-reference-score-is-ambiguous) but it could not help me solve the problem. Anyone have solutions?

Comment: table `detail_t` must have column `cmt_cnt` ?..

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable that have the same name of a column. The query parser could not decide which it must chose, change your variable name then the ambiguity will vanish.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html

> By default, PL/pgSQL will report an error if a name in a SQL statement
>   could refer to either a variable or a table column. You can fix such a
>   problem by renaming the variable or column, or by qualifying the
>   ambiguous reference, or by telling PL/pgSQL which interpretation to
>   prefer. **The simplest solution is to rename the variable or column**. A common 
>   coding rule is to use a different naming convention for PL/pgSQL
>   variables than you use for column names. For example, if you
>   consistently name function variables v_something while none of your
>   column names start with v_, no conflicts will occur.

and further:

> You can also set the behavior on a function-by-function basis, by
>   inserting one of these special commands at the start of the function
>   text:
>
> ```
> #variable_conflict error
> #variable_conflict use_variable
> #variable_conflict use_column
> ```